# How to speed up 2D arrays in 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am looking at how to speed up one of my functions. The function is called with a number of two-dimensional arrays of the same size. I want to combine these into a 4D with 3x3 in the last two dimensions, and later get the eigenvalues of the whole array.

I have managed to do it using two nested `for` loops, but it is a bit slower then I would desire, so is there any good way of speeding up the code?

```
def principal(xx, xy, xz, yy, yz, zz):

    import numpy as np

    xx = np.array(xx)
    xy = np.array(xy)
    xz = np.array(xz)
    yy = np.array(yy)
    yz = np.array(yz)
    zz = np.array(zz)

    size = np.shape(xx)
    Princ = np.empty((size[1], size[0], 3, 3))
    for j in range(size[1]):
        for i in range(size[0]):
            Princ[j, i, :, :] = np.array([[xx[i, j], xy[i, j], xz[i, j]],
                                          [xy[i, j], yy[i, j], yz[i, j]],
                                          [xz[i, j], yz[i, j], zz[i, j]]])
    Princ = np.linalg.eigvalsh(Princ)

    return Princ


import numpy as np

number_arrays_1 = 3
number_arrays_2 = 4

xx = np.ones((number_arrays_1, number_arrays_2))*80
xy = np.ones((number_arrays_1, number_arrays_2))*30
xz = np.ones((number_arrays_1, number_arrays_2))*0
yy = np.ones((number_arrays_1, number_arrays_2))*40
yz = np.ones((number_arrays_1, number_arrays_2))*0
zz = np.ones((number_arrays_1, number_arrays_2))*60

Princ = principal(xx, xy, xz, yy, yz, zz)
print(Princ)
```

The reason I convert with `xx = np.array(xx)` is that in the larger program, I pass a pandas dataframe rather than a numpy array into the function.

Comment: You are importing numpy 2 times and for each function call. You should move them to the top of the script

Comment: The function principal which i define is usually located in a separate file which i then import into the main file for usage. I believe that i have to import the modules used within each function that i define, or is that not true?

Comment: @DogukanAltay, the extra imports are not a problem.

Comment: Will the `xx` etc always be `np.ones(....)*c`?  Or is that just convenience for this example?

Comment: It is just for this this example, they will be very different as they are output from an simulation. It is just so that I can see there is gives the correct value (I know what the eigenvalues are which are evaluated at the end)

Comment: It may be faster to call `...values()` on the dataframe than `np.array(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple stack and reshape operation:

```
def principal(xx, xy, xz, yy, yz, zz):
    princ = np.stack((xx.T, xy.T, xz.T, xy.T, yy.T, yz.T, xz.T, yz.T, zz.T), axis=-1).reshape(*xx.shape[::-1], 3, 3)
    return = np.linalg.eigvalsh(princ)
```

You don't need to explicitly call `np.array` on the inputs if they are already arrays. `xx.values()` on the dataframes should return the numpy values.

An alternative approach is to build the array, and then swap out the 3x3 dimensions to the back. This will likely be less efficient since the first approach makes the 3x3 dimensions contiguous, while this one does not:

```
princ = np.array([[xx, xy, xz], [xy, yy, yz], [xz, yz, zz]]).T
```

Not really related, but you could generate your arrays faster like this:

```
target_shape = (3, 4)
values = np.array([80, 30, 0, 40, 0, 60])
xx, xy, xz, yy, yz, zz = np.full((6, *target_shape), values.reshape(-1, 1, 1))
```

In fact, if your data allows it, you can even save on unpacking:

```
data = np.full((6, *target_shape), values.reshape(-1, 1, 1))
principal(*data)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, the first way with the stacking and then reshaping almost worked but i had to transpose the xx, xy etc to get it to the proper shape. In the for loops the notation from my previous function is Princ[j, i, :, :] = x[i, j]... so they are swapped due to how the data is feed into and out of the function later. But once i transposed the arrays it works well, went from about 3-4 minutes of calculations to about 30s so i would consider that a win! Also thanks for notifying me skip the conversion of xx = np.array(xx) i think this also saves some memory and time.

Comment: Will also try to use the .value(), or as it is stated in the pandas documentation .to_numpy() to see if that also helps.

Comment: @RasmusSchützer. I've fixed the answer to implement the transpose properly